# How to use CMake to construct an OpenSceneGraph project?

Tags: cmake, openscenegraph

I have just downloaded the OpenSceneGraph source, unzip it into
"~/OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1" directory and use CMake to create an out-of-source
eclipse make project in "~/OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1-build-eclipse-cdt"
directory. When I execute "make" in
"~/OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1-build-eclipse-cdt" directory, OpenSceneGraph builds
successfully. I have not run "sudo make install" as I do not want to
install OpenSceneGraph tightly into my Ubuntu system.

Now I want to use CMake to create a project using the compiled
OpenSceneGraph libraries. I use the following codes in CMakeLists.txt :

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT( test_proj )
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenSceneGraph)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test test.cpp )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OPENSCENEGRAPH_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test ${OPENSCENEGRAPH_LIBRARIES} )
```

But it seems that OpenSceneGraph could not be found by CMake.

Does anyone know how CMake could find the compiled OpenSceneGraph
libraries in the "~/OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1-build-eclipse-cdt" directory and
use it to create projects as if I have tightly installed OpenSceneGraph
using "sudo make install". Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What changes did you make to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to install OpenSceneGraph system-wide. Just choose a CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX that suits you (eg. ~/osg).

Using the install command makes sure that everything is correctly in place (i.e. in the correct directory structure) for `FindOpenSceneGraph.cmake` (the script CMake invokes when you call `FIND_PACKAGE( OpenSceneGraph )` ) to find it.

Then, you should point any of `OSG_DIR`, `OSGDIR`, or `OSG_ROOT` as environment variable and point it to your install location, so CMake knows where to look for it.

**Edit:** 
@Hugues: I'll try to make it a bit clearer:

Setup up OpenSceneGraph:

1. Get OSG source.
2. When running CMake for it, choose a `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` that suits you, eg. `~/osg` if you don't want a system-wide installation in (default) `/usr/local`. Do it either by stating `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/hugues/osg` on the command-line or by setting it using a gui tool like `ccmake` or `cmake-gui`.
3. Run `make install` to build and install OSG.
4. Set the environment variable `OSG_DIR` to whatever you pointed `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`. (`export OSG_DIR=<whereever_you_installed_osg>`)

Setup your project:

1. In your `CMakeLists.txt`, use `FIND_PACKAGE( OpenSceneGraph )` (add desired optional arguments as desired).
2. Use the resulting variables (like `${OpenSceneGraph_LIBRARIES}` in the appropriate places in your cmake file.
3. Run CMake for your project.

Comment: How does the CMakeLists.txt look like then? I'm sorry I do not understand your instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Add this below command in your CMakeLists.txt:
`list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")`

Then put the file `FindOpenSceneGraph.cmake` in `src/cmake` dir.

FindOpenSceneGraph.cmake can be found [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindOpenSceneGraph.cmake).